# How to find Exact Target Import error details

Tags: exacttarget

My Exact Target import failed with error status. No rows with errors, no successful rows.
How I can find error details?

Comment: You'll get a lot more eyes on your SFMC questions over at [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com), specifically with the [Marketing-Cloud](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marketing-cloud) tag.

Comment: Thank you @Adam Spriggs, I found that only way is checking "... Results NNNNN.txt" file.

Comment: import from the ftp?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in "Import" folder you will find "*****Result****.txt" file created at the error time in which you can find details on the error